# Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Username) giving error in MVC3 RC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This was working before in RC1 but in RC2 not working. Any idea whats wrong?

```
Line 97:         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
Line 98:         @Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Username) ---> ERROR HERE
Line 99:         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Learning.Ajax.Models.Order>' does not contain a definition for 'TextboxFor' and no extension method 'TextboxFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Learning.Ajax.Models.Order>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be `TextBoxFor` (with capital B)